# How to compute $\int {\frac{1}{{4 - 9{x^2}}}dx} $?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I evaluate the following integral

$$\int {\frac{1}{{4 - 9{x^2}}}dx} $$

Comment: It's $\int \frac{dx}{(2+3x)(2-3x)}$, then use [Partial Fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution.Consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) an useful answe.  You could have looked up on Wolfram Alpha

Answer (score 3):

Notice, use partial fractions as follows $$\int \frac{dx}{4-9x^2}=\int \frac{dx}{(2-3x)(2+3x)}$$
$$=\int \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2-3x}+\frac{1}{2+3x}\right)\ dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\int \left(\frac{1}{2-3x}+\frac{1}{2+3x}\right)\ dx$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The derivative of $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ is $$\frac 1{1-x^2}.$$
Then the integral will be of the form $$a\tanh^{-1}(bx).$$

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it this term reminding arctanh derivative ? :-)
for $\frac{1}{a+b x^2}$ -like integrands, first re-check $arctan(ax)$ and $arctanh(ax)$ derivatives, choose the best appropriate, then fit to your numbers.

Comment: It's confusing to mention $\frac{1}{a+bx^2}$ and then $\arctan(ax)$, when the real point is that $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(ax)=\frac{a}{1-a^2x^2}$. No need for $\arctan$, just use implicit differentiation on $\tanh y=ax$ and use the identity $\tanh^2 y+\mathrm{sech}^2 y=1$. I don't think the answer deserves two downvotes, though, as it does suggest a viable approach. +1

Comment: Who deleted this answer, and why ???

Comment: I guess we are here to give some useful knowledge and generalities, not just all-cooked solutions. I do think telling how to address the just a bit more general pattern of $\frac{1}{a+bx^2}$ is an appropriate way to answer. I've cpolished it a bit, though.

Comment: The post was deleted from the review queue (it was automatically put in the queue since it was so short). Apparently, the reviewers considered the original version to be not an answer. Make your answers a bit longer to avoid such things.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.  Deletion without explaination feels extremely rude; isn't it at least possible to send a private message in such case ?